# Should I tear down all resources constructed in __init__?

Tags: python

Quite often I create classes which internally use some resources like requests sessions, IMAP connections. I initialize such resources in `__init__`.

For example:

```
class SomeClass:
    def __init__(self, login, password):
        self.session = requests.Session()
        self.imap_connection = IMAPLib.connect(...)
        ... and so on ...
```

So the main question: should I manually free such resources, like sessions, imap_connections or it's quite safe to let them die when the GC runs or it's not safe and if so what is best solution?

As I understand besides implementing some `free_resources` method and invoking it explicitly is to implement `__enter__` which returns `self` and an `__exit__` method which tears all these resources down. Then I instantiate these class using a `with` block.

Answer (score 0):

Context manager support (support for `with` blocks) is the most portable, consistent approach. Otherwise, assuming the resources define their own `__del__` cleanup, then, barring reference loops, in CPython they'll be cleaned up when the owner instance loses its last reference. Unfortunately, if there *is* a cycle, prior to CPython 3.4, the presence of a `__del__` finalizer in the cycle will prevent the cyclic GC from cleaning the cycle at all, so memory leaks and no finalizers are invoked. In 3.4+, it will probably, eventually be cleaned, but the timing won't be deterministic thanks to the need for cyclic collection to occur.

Comment: Also in case of exception without a `with` block the `__del__` method  will not be called on these objects?

Comment: In CPython, it will be when the reference count goes to zero (so in most cases, when the function returns/the exception bubbles out of the function and the traceback is cleaned). But yes, `with` allows deterministic cleanup immediately at a known point, rather than "when the object goes away sometime".